# Laravel - ErrorException : Array to string conversion

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem in this code in Laravel when using php artisan route:list

```
    ErrorException  : Array to string conversion

  at /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/Merchant/CountryAreaController.php:312
    308|             }
    309|         }
    310|         if (!empty($request->rental_service)) {
    311|             $service[] = 2;
  > 312|             foreach ($request->get('rental_vehicle_type' . []) as $item) {
    313|                 $area->VehicleType()->attach($item, ['service_type_id' => 2]);
    314|             }
    315|             $area->Package()->attach($request->rental_service, ['service_type_id' => 2]);
    316|         }
```

Comment: Why do you have to concatante `'rental_vehicle_type' . []` ? Why not just `'rental_vehicle_type[]'` ?

Comment: To be honest its a really old project that I got now not sure why gonna try

Comment: Another error when i try with line 313 check the code up Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : syntax error, unexpected 'service_type_id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: So the `Array to string conversion` error got fixed and you have an additional error ?

Comment: Yes but i fixed them by
            foreach ($request->get('rental_vehicle_type' . array_values([])) as $item) {
I added array_values() for some reason and all got worked thank you !

Answer (score 0):

At the line of the error I changed

```
foreach ($request->get('rental_vehicle_type' . []) as $item) {
```

to

```
foreach ($request->get('rental_vehicle_type' . array_values([])) as $item) {
```

`array_values()` Solved it i don't know why